# VBA if then function always returning 0

Tags: excel, vba

My friend and I have searched the internet for an answer. I am fairly new to VBA and my Function is always returning 0. Some help with this would be great. Below is my code:

```
Function OnlineAbs(x As Date, y As Date, z As Date)

    If x > 0 Then
        If y > 0 Then
             result = "Online - Images"
        Else
            If z > 0 Then
                result = "Online - DT Images"
            Else
                result = "Online - No Images"
            End If
        End If
    Else
        result = "Abstract"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Replace `result` with `OnlineAbs`

Comment: or add `OnlineAbs = result` just before `End Function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function returns in VBA is a little *different*. Setting the value you want to be returned to the function name will return that value.

```
Function OnlineAbs(x As Date, y As Date, z As Date)

    If x > 0 Then
        If y > 0 Then
             OnlineAbs = "Online - Images"
        Else
            If z > 0 Then
                OnlineAbs = "Online - DT Images"
            Else
                OnlineAbs = "Online - No Images"
            End If
        End If
    Else
        OnlineAbs = "Abstract"
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple issues with this code snippet:

1. A minor syntax error: in order to correct it keeping the code changes minimal, just add a line statement before function end (as suggested by Siddharth Rout), i.e. `OnlineAbs = result` before `End Function`.
2. More serious issue is a potential flaw in business logic (possible type mismatch): `DateTime` type in Excel Worksheet/VBA has an underlying value (e.g., the worksheet function for current DateTime will return: `=VALUE(NOW()) = 42153.53481`; in VBA corresponding function is CDbl(x)), which is >0 for most practical cases for any Date following 1/1/1900 (the underlying value of 1/1/1900 is 1); thus, your function will return `"Online - Images"` for any Date after 1/1/1900.

I would recommend to verify your business logic. Kind regards